# collection with dynamic multiple tables using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a collection which need to be displayed as table one by one. 
For example in the collection 0 it can contain a list of 2 records and each record can contains 3 columns.- this has to be displayed in the table 1

Next in the collection 1 it can contain a list of 3 record and each record can contains 3 columns- this has to be displayed in the table 2

this collection is running in a loop and i have to repeat it based on the the collection Items

below is the knock code

```
function TestPageModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.MHxReport = ko.observableArray([]);

    function addMHxReport(columnList ) {
        return {
            ColumnList: ko.observableArray(columnList)            
        }
    }

    function add(term, mhstdat,mhendat) {
        return {            
            Term: ko.observable(term),
            Mhstdat: ko.observable(mhstdat),            
            Mhendat: ko.observable(mhendat)
        }
    }

    var cList = [];
    var columnList = [];
    var aList = [];

    cList.push(new add("cough", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
    cList.push(new add("ashtma", "13MAR2018", "06NOV2018"));

    aList.push(new add("blood", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
    aList.push(new add("ear", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
    aList.push(new add("head", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));

    columnList[0] = cList;
    columnList[1] = aList;

    var newobj = new addMHxReport(columnList )
    self.MHxReport.push(newobj);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var testPageModel = new TestPageModel();    
    ko.applyBindings(TestPageModel);
});
```

below is the html code

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: MHxReport">
        <div style="margin:12px 0 12px 0;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">             
                <div class="table-responsive dsg-btm-shadow" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0 0 15px 0px;" >
                    <table class="dsg-setup dsg-aligntop" border="0" >
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ColumnList" >
                            <tr>
                                <td><span data-bind='text: $data'></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Problem is i am not able to display it as a table of rows and columns. Not sure
what is missing and how to get the code to work to display in rows and columns.
can any one help.  Please thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `ColumnList` is an array of arrays. So, `text: $data` will show `[object Object],[object Object]`. According to your question, you want to display them in multiple tables but you are creating a single table. So, move the `foreach: ColumnList` to outside the `table` part.

```js
function TestPageModel() {

  var self = this;
  self.MHxReport = ko.observableArray([]);

  function addMHxReport(columnList) {
    return {
      ColumnList: ko.observableArray(columnList)
    }
  }

  function add(term, mhstdat, mhendat) {
    return {
      Term: ko.observable(term),
      Mhstdat: ko.observable(mhstdat),
      Mhendat: ko.observable(mhendat)
    }
  }

  var cList = [];
  var columnList = [];
  var aList = [];

  cList.push(new add("cough", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
  cList.push(new add("ashtma", "13MAR2018", "06NOV2018"));

  aList.push(new add("blood", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
  aList.push(new add("ear", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
  aList.push(new add("head", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));

  columnList.push(cList, aList)

  var newobj = new addMHxReport(columnList)
  self.MHxReport.push(newobj);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var testPageModel = new TestPageModel();
  ko.applyBindings(TestPageModel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: MHxReport">
  <div style="margin:12px 0 12px 0;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="table-responsive dsg-btm-shadow" data-bind="foreach: ColumnList">
      <span data-bind="text: 'table '+$index()"></span>
        <table class="dsg-setup dsg-aligntop table" style="padding:10px" border="0">
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <tr>
              <td><span data-bind='text: Term'></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind='text: Mhstdat'></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind='text: Mhendat'></span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br> <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click on "Run code snippet" to test it out. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tb5osqr/) as well.

**UPDATE**:

If you're unsure of the column names beforehand and want to get them from the object, then you can loop through each Object's [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then bind the `value` for that key to the `td`. Like this:

```js
function TestPageModel() {

  var self = this;
  self.MHxReport = ko.observableArray([]);

  function addMHxReport(columnList) {
    return {
      ColumnList: ko.observableArray(columnList)
    }
  }

  function add(term, mhstdat, mhendat) {
    return {
      Term: ko.observable(term),
      Mhstdat: ko.observable(mhstdat),
      Mhendat: ko.observable(mhendat)
    }
  }

  var columnList = [];
  var cList = [];

  cList.push(new add("cough", "13MAR2018", "10SEP2018"));
  cList.push(new add("ashtma", "13MAR2018", "06NOV2018"));

  // Has five columns
  var aList = [{
      Term: ko.observable("eyes"),
      Diagnosis:ko.observable("surgery"),
      Type:ko.observable("Major"),
      Mhstdat: ko.observable("19NOV2018"),
      Mhendat: ko.observable("20NOV2018"),
    },
    {
      Term: ko.observable("hands"),
      Diagnosis:ko.observable("transplant"),
      Type:ko.observable("Critical"),
      Mhstdat: ko.observable("21NOV2018"),
      Mhendat: ko.observable("22NOV2018"),
    }
  ];

  columnList.push(cList, aList)

  var newobj = new addMHxReport(columnList)
  self.MHxReport.push(newobj);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var testPageModel = new TestPageModel();
  ko.applyBindings(TestPageModel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: MHxReport">
  <div style="margin:12px 0 12px 0;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="table-responsive dsg-btm-shadow" data-bind="foreach: ColumnList">
        <span data-bind="text: 'table '+$index()"></span>
        <table class="dsg-setup dsg-aligntop table" style="padding:10px" border="0">
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys($data), as: 'key' }">
              <td><span data-bind='text: $parent[key]'></span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br> <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the shake of example i have given the function "add" and to bring the understanding. However in real scenerio,  suppose, first table can contain only 2 columns, Second table can contains 3 columns, third table can contain 5 columns. So using the loop i need to display the data invariably of the columns i have in the table. Please suggest and help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @jaiganesh this is why you should create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. Because from the question it looks like you have only 3 columns. Anyway, I have updated the answer to handle different number of columns dynamically.

Comment: this update was useful in getting the required functionality. For the shake of understanding i have kept it has simple. However i require 2 more things. - table should displaying heading which comes in the table collections and also it should be able to do sorting functionality in the table. Please suggest and help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @jaiganesh Table header should be easy. Please go through the updated answer and understand it. I have already shown how to loop through the keys. Now, you just have to loop through the keys and bind them to `th`s.  Sorting, really? I have already answered your question and additional functionality you added in comments. Sorry, I cannot do those *2 more things*. People on stackoverflow are **volunteering** their time to help you when you're stuck. Please respect that.  This is Q and A site. **Not a free code-writing service**.

Comment: for the purpose of debugging the html part , using console.log for the "$data" i can see only the arrays. However to understand what is happening inside "Object.Keys" and how to use them to get the name of the column name is not understanding to me. If there a better way to debug and understand the flow Please suggest and help.

Comment: i am not able to get  a logical conclusion as the above solution does not support following behavior of the column. For example i am not able to control the first column in the table to be hyperlink . Second i am not able to control the third column to be hidden from the UI display. Please suggest and help

Comment: @jaiganesh You can make any column as hyperlink based on the index or the name of the column. You should use [container-less control flow syntax](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element). Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tb5osqr/1/) demonstrating that. This is the last time I'm replying in this thread. I have told you before. I'm not your free tech support for you to demand new features from me. Go through the documentation and some fiddles. There are thousands of examples online to do the most complex features.